# Why button inside hidden view still get focus tvOS

Tags: tvos

I have 2 buttons A and B, button B is inside a hidden view.
The button A is focused, but when I swipe the remote, it moves focus from button A to button B, although it is inside a hidden view. Now we see the focus has disappeared from the screen.

[image]